# AES CBC encrypt/decrypt only decrypts the first 16 bytes

Tags: c++, openssl, aes

I'm doing some work with AES CBC and openssl and for now, I'm stuck on a problem that i cannot guess what's wrong (as always).

Given a message less than 16 bytes length the process of encryption and decryption works fine, but when the message is greater than 16 bytes the decryption works only on the 16th first bytes.

When i call `aes.exe stackoverflow stackoverflow` the output is:

```
Using:
IVector   = |000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f|
Key       = |737461636b6f766572666c6f770d0e0f101112131415161718191a1b1c1d1e1f|
Encrypted = |6c65219594c0dae778f9b5e84f018db6|

Encrypting : stackoverflow
With Key   : stackoverflow
Becomes    :  ??????¤le!òö++þx¨ÁÞO?ìÂ.

Using:
IVector   = |000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f|
Key       = |737461636b6f766572666c6f770d0e0f101112131415161718191a1b1c1d1e1f|
Decrypted = |737461636b6f766572666c6f77|

Decrypting :  ??????¤le!òö++þx¨ÁÞO?ìÂ
With Key   : stackoverflow
Becomes    : stackoverflow
```

When i call `aes.exe stackoverflowstackoverflow stackoverflow` the output is:

```
Using:
IVector   = |000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f|
Key       = |737461636b6f766572666c6f770d0e0f101112131415161718191a1b1c1d1e1f|
Encrypted = |46172e3f7fabdcfc6c8b3e65aef175cddf8164236faf706112c15f5e765e49a5|

Encrypting : stackoverflowstackoverflow
With Key   : stackoverflow
Becomes    :  ??????¤F?.?¦½_³lï>e«±u-¯üd#o»pa?-_^v^IÑ.

Using:
IVector   = |000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f|
Key       = |737461636b6f766572666c6f770d0e0f101112131415161718191a1b1c1d1e1f|
Decrypted = |737461636b6f766572666c6f77737461257d434a1edcbc970bf5346ea2fc7bc2|

Decrypting :  ??????¤F?.?¦½_³lï>e«±u-¯üd#o»pa?-_^v^IÑ
With Key   : stackoverflow
Becomes    : stackoverflowsta%}CJ?_+ù?§4nó³{-.
```

I'm providing a random IV for each encryption/decryption call and normalizing the password at 32 bytes in both cases; what I'm missing? anyone knows?

The source code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

// Make a Key of exactly 32 bytes, truncates or adds values if it's necessary
std::string AES_NormalizeKey(const void *const apBuffer, size_t aSize)
{
    static const unsigned char key32[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31};
    const char *const Buffer = reinterpret_cast<const char *>(apBuffer);
    std::string Result(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(key32), 32);
    std::copy(Buffer, Buffer + ((aSize < 32)? aSize: 32), Result.begin());
    return Result;
}

// Encrypt using AES cbc
std::string AESEncrypt(const void *const apBuffer, size_t aBufferSize, const void *const apKey, size_t aKeySize, std::string &aIVector)
{
    // Create IVector.
    unsigned char AES_IVector[16] = {0};
    std::srand(static_cast<int>(time(NULL)));
    std::generate(std::begin(AES_IVector), std::end(AES_IVector), std::rand);
    std::copy(std::begin(AES_IVector), std::end(AES_IVector), aIVector.begin());

    // Create key.
    const std::string Key(AES_NormalizeKey(apKey, aKeySize));
    AES_KEY EncryptKey;
    AES_set_encrypt_key(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char *>(Key.c_str()), 256, &EncryptKey);

    // Encrypt.
    unsigned char AES_Encrypted[1024] = {0};
    AES_cbc_encrypt(static_cast<const unsigned char *>(apBuffer), AES_Encrypted, aBufferSize, &EncryptKey, AES_IVector, AES_ENCRYPT);
    const std::string Encrypted(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(AES_Encrypted), ((aBufferSize / 16) + 1) * 16);

    // Finish.
    return Encrypted;
};

// Decrypt using AES cbc
std::string AESDecrypt(const void *const apBuffer, size_t aBufferSize, const void *const apKey, size_t aKeySize, std::string &aIVector)
{
    // Read IVector.
    unsigned char AES_IVector[16] = {0};
    std::copy(aIVector.begin(), aIVector.end(), std::begin(AES_IVector));

    // Create Key.
    const std::string Key(AES_NormalizeKey(apKey, aKeySize));
    AES_KEY DecryptKey;
    AES_set_decrypt_key(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char *>(Key.c_str()), 256, &DecryptKey);

    // Decrypt.
    unsigned char AES_Decrypted[1024] = {0};
    AES_cbc_encrypt(static_cast<const unsigned char *>(apBuffer), AES_Decrypted, aBufferSize, &DecryptKey, AES_IVector, AES_DECRYPT);
    const std::string Decrypted(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(AES_Decrypted));

    // Finish.
    return Decrypted;
};

// Entry point
int main(unsigned int argc, char **argv)
{
    typedef std::vector<const std::string> vs;
    vs a;

    for (vs::size_type Index = 0; Index < argc; ++Index)
    {
        a.push_back(argv[Index]);
    }

    if (a.size() == 3)
    {
        std::string IV("");

        std::string e(AESEncrypt(a.at(1).c_str(), a.at(1).size(), a.at(2).c_str(), a.at(2).size()), IV);
            std::cout << "Encrypting : " << a.at(1) << "\n"
                      << "With Key   : " << a.at(2) << "\n"
                      << "Becomes    : " << e << ".\n";

        std::string d(AESDecrypt(e.c_str(), e.size(), a.at(2).c_str(), a.at(2).size()), IV);
            std::cout << "Decrypting : " << e << "\n"
                      << "With Key   : " << a.at(2) << "\n"
                      << "Becomes    : " << d << ".\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should *not* use `AES_encrypt` and friends. You should be using `EVP_*` functions. See [EVP Symmetric Encryption and Decryption](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption) on the OpenSSL wiki. In fact, you should probably be using authenticated encryption because it provides *both* confidentiality and authenticity. See [EVP Authenticated Encryption and Decryption](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Authenticated_Encryption_and_Decryption) on the OpenSSL wiki.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code is almost correct, except that the initialization vector is being overwritten due to memory corruption, the length of the ciphertext is rounded incorrectly, and std::string::data() should be used instead of std::string::c_str() when using std::string as a byte array. The Initialization Vector is copied into the empty string overwriting the stack. Then the Initialization Vector gets overwritten so different value is used by AESDecrypt. I've included source code that incorporates indiv's suggestions and fixes these problems. When run with

```
aes "Hello World!" stackoverflow
```

it produces the following output:

```
(Normalized key: 737461636b6f766572666c6f770d0e0f101112131415161718191a1b1c1d1e1f)
Encrypting : Hello World!
With Key   : stackoverflow
Init Vec   : d8b1657d9e2317c93430994f59bb54eb
Becomes    : ��Йw�H���}�;E
(Normalized key: 737461636b6f766572666c6f770d0e0f101112131415161718191a1b1c1d1e1f)
Decrypting : ��Йw�H���}�;E
With Key   : stackoverflow
Init Vec   : d8b1657d9e2317c93430994f59bb54eb
Becomes    : Hello World!
```

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <algorithm>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <openssl/aes.h>

typedef unsigned char byte;

template <size_t multiple> size_t round_up(const size_t len)
{
    if (len % multiple == 0) return len;
    else return ((len / multiple) + 1) * multiple;
}

std::ostream &print_buffer_as_hex(std::ostream &o, const unsigned char *buf, size_t size)
{
    o << std::hex << std::setfill('0');
    for( size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i )
    {
        o << std::setw(2) << static_cast<unsigned int>(buf[i]);
    }
    return o << std::dec;
}

inline std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &o, const std::vector<byte> &buf)
{
    return print_buffer_as_hex(o, reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(&buf[0]), buf.size());
}

// Make a Key of exactly 32 bytes, truncates or adds values if it's necessary
std::string AES_NormalizeKey(const void *const apBuffer, size_t aSize)
{
    static const unsigned char key32[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31};
    const char *const Buffer = reinterpret_cast<const char *>(apBuffer);
    std::string Result(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(key32), 32);
    std::copy(Buffer, Buffer + ((aSize < 32)? aSize: 32), Result.begin());
    return Result;
}

// Encrypt using AES cbc
std::string AESEncrypt(const void *const apBuffer, size_t aBufferSize, const void *const apKey, size_t aKeySize, std::vector<byte> &aIVector)
{
    // Create IVector.
    unsigned char AES_IVector[AES_BLOCK_SIZE] = {0};
    std::srand(static_cast<int>(time(NULL)));
    std::generate(std::begin(AES_IVector), std::end(AES_IVector), std::rand);
    aIVector.resize(sizeof(AES_IVector));
    std::copy(std::begin(AES_IVector), std::end(AES_IVector), aIVector.begin());

    // Create key.
    const std::string Key(AES_NormalizeKey(apKey, aKeySize));
    std::cout << "(Normalized key: ";
    print_buffer_as_hex(std::cout, (const unsigned char*)Key.data(), Key.size()) << ")\n";
    AES_KEY EncryptKey;
    AES_set_encrypt_key(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char *>(Key.data()), 256, &EncryptKey);

    // Encrypt.
    unsigned char AES_Encrypted[1024] = {0};
    AES_cbc_encrypt(static_cast<const unsigned char *>(apBuffer), AES_Encrypted, aBufferSize, &EncryptKey, AES_IVector, AES_ENCRYPT);
    const std::string Encrypted(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(AES_Encrypted), round_up<AES_BLOCK_SIZE>(aBufferSize));

    // Finish.
    return Encrypted;
};

// Decrypt using AES cbc
std::string AESDecrypt(const void *const apBuffer, size_t aBufferSize, const void *const apKey, size_t aKeySize, std::vector<byte> &aIVector)
{
    // Read IVector.
    unsigned char AES_IVector[AES_BLOCK_SIZE] = {0};
    std::copy(aIVector.begin(), aIVector.end(), std::begin(AES_IVector));

    // Create Key.
    const std::string Key(AES_NormalizeKey(apKey, aKeySize));
    std::cout << "(Normalized key: ";
    print_buffer_as_hex(std::cout, (const unsigned char*)Key.data(), Key.size()) << ")\n";
    AES_KEY DecryptKey;
    AES_set_decrypt_key(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char *>(Key.data()), 256, &DecryptKey);

    // Decrypt.
    unsigned char AES_Decrypted[1024] = {0};
    AES_cbc_encrypt(static_cast<const unsigned char *>(apBuffer), AES_Decrypted, aBufferSize, &DecryptKey, AES_IVector, AES_DECRYPT);
    const std::string Decrypted(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(AES_Decrypted));

    // Finish.
    return Decrypted;
};

// Entry point
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    typedef std::vector<std::string> vs;
    vs a;

    for (vs::size_type Index = 0; Index < static_cast<unsigned>(argc); ++Index)
    {
        a.push_back(argv[Index]);
    }

    if (a.size() == 3)
    {
        std::vector<byte> IV;

        std::string e(AESEncrypt(a.at(1).data(), a.at(1).size(), a.at(2).data(), a.at(2).size(), IV));
            std::cout << "Encrypting : " << a.at(1) << "\n"
                      << "With Key   : " << a.at(2) << "\n"
                      << "Init Vec   : " << IV << "\n"
                      << "Becomes    : " << e << "\n";

        std::string d(AESDecrypt(e.data(), e.size(), a.at(2).data(), a.at(2).size(), IV));
            std::cout << "Decrypting : " << e << "\n"
                      << "With Key   : " << a.at(2) << "\n"
                      << "Init Vec   : " << IV << "\n"
                      << "Becomes    : " << d << "\n";
    }
    std::cout.flush();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Great! I've tested it and now is working properly! as for the rounding I had fixed it a few days ago (but as the topic looked dead I don't mention it) but the use of `data` instead of `c_str` is a very good point!

Comment: I'm glad I could help!  One tiny clarification: whether or not writing into an empty string overwrites the stack in this case is implementation dependant. Most std::string implementations use the "small string optimization" (i.e. store small strings inside the object), so I suspect that is what was happening here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a concrete answer, but here's a tip that won't fit in a comment.  Encrypt and decrypt require the same key and IV to work.  The output of the encrypt function must go into the input of the decrypt function.

So to debug your problem, you need to print out your inputs to the encrypt function and print its output.  Then you need to print the input data to the decrypt function and print its output.  Plain text is a bad way to do this, because you can't see what the bytes really are.  So print the key, IV, and data as hex values.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
...
std::ostream &print_buffer_as_hex(std::ostream &o, const unsigned char *buf, size_t size)
{
    for( int i = 0; i < size; ++i )
    {
        o << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << static_cast<unsigned int>(buf[i]) << std::dec;
    }
    o << "\n";

    return o;
}
```

Call it like so:

```
print_buffer_as_hex(std::cout, reinterpret_cast<const char *>(AES_Encrypted), ((aBufferSize / 16) + 1) * 16);
```

I'd use `std::vector<unsigned char>` instead of `std::string` to hold arbitrary bytes. Set the amount of space you want with the constructor or the `resize()` method (resize(), not reserve()!).  If you call an API function that wants an `unsigned char *`, just pass `&vec[0]`, where vec is your vector object.  Your code will look a lot cleaner.

E.g.,

```
std::vector<unsigned char> iv(16);
std::srand(static_cast<int>(time(NULL)));
std::generate(iv.begin(), iv.end(), std::rand);

print_buffer_as_hex(std::cout, &iv[0], iv.size());
```

Comment: Constructing the `std::string Encrypted` isn't the problem, i know about the n parameter on `std::string` constructor and the `((aBufferSize / 16) + 1) * 16)` is there on purpose, cause AES encryption always creates chunks of multiple of 16bytes of data, so if the message is 12bytes the encryption are 16 and if the message is 17bytes of data the encryption are 32 bytes. I'll put the intermediate bytes on hexa as sugested.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster:  Well I learned something new today.  I was completely wrong how the `std::string` constructor worked with binary data and the `n` parameter.  Thanks for pointing it out and I've edited my answer accordingly.